# How to change Action bar for each Tab in Nativescript Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I hav TabBar app using Nativescript Angular. I want to change the Action Bar buttons based on the selected tab.
I just follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7go3L70QfIQ

But, don't know how to use TabView.selectedIndexChangedEvent in Angular.
If anyone has done this, please share the piece of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue using rxjs/Observable notifications. Logic is post a notification when the tab changes happen. Based on the tab index, I can decide the action bar button tap event methods.

```
    // send notify to child components
    let message = {
        "tabIndex" : this.tabIndex,
        "tappedButton" : "someButton"
    };
    this.notifyService.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [this example](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/2fc485afbdcc22b3eeaad4755819e49e6cf42da2/app/ui-category/tab-view/basic-tab-view/basic-tab-view.component.html#L2) as a reference on how to use the selectedIndexChange event in Angular based application.

For example:

```
<TabView selectedIndex="0"  (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)">
<!-- more code follows here -->
```

And then in the component file use the onIndexChanged callback

```
public onIndexChanged(args) {
    let tabView = <TabView>args.object;
    console.log("Selected index changed! New inxed: " + tabView.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, Yes I already followed that example. I can get the tab index in the tab.component.ts. But my question is how to change the navigation bar items based on the selected tab index. Think, my app has 3 tabs. Each tab has different layout files. Now, I want to have "search" button on the action bar for 1st tab and respective action method. "edit" button for the 2nd tab so on... how can i achieve that?

Comment: Once you are "attached" to the `selectedIndexChange` you can show/hide predefined ActionBar Items - example is shown here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#hiding-action-items

Comment: Yep, I can do whatever in the Tab.component.ts. But how to detect action bar button tap methods in child component?

Comment: If a user taps  (no matter in or out the ActionBar) all you need is to track the tapEvent for the tapped layout (e.g Button) and implement the logic in the callback. So if you need a user to change something when he taps the ActionBar button than you need to access the wanted layout e.g via `getViewById()` method

Comment: Sorry if my requirement is still not clear. Let me explain... lets say I have two tabs as "Person" and "Job". Each has its ow .ts file and .html file. Now in tab.component I have created the action bar with "Add" button. Now, both Person and "Job" tabs can see the "Add" button. Now I want to fire "addPerson()" method and "addJob()" method when user clicks the "Add" button in respective pages.

Comment: In the linked example there are three different callbacks called `onEdit`, `onSave`and `onCancel`. n the code behind file there are three different respective callbacks for each different ActionItem (which on the other hand  can be visible/collapsed based in the selectedIndexChange) - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#hiding-action-items

Comment: Tha above sounds just like the functionality you need for addPerson and addJob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160524/discussion-between-sajaz-and-nick-iliev).

Comment: Find me in the NativeScript community slack channel - username: niki_iliev

Comment: Nick lliev thanks for the help. I have solve the issue. Have posted the answer.